# Trouble creating bookmarklet

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

Im trying to create a bookmarklet

Here is the html code

```
<input id="entername" name="" placeholder="" value="" size="36" maxlength="10" type="text">
```

Here is my JS code

```
javascript:function%20D(a,b){c=b.split('|');d=false;for(q=0;q<c.length;q++){if(c[q]==a)d=true;}return%20d;}function%20E(){f0=document.forms[0];f0['entername'].value='vincent';}E()
```

Sadly it doesn't paste the name vincent in the box. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

When I create a test case consisting of a form containing that markup, the bookmarklet works.

Presumably, therefore, either:

- The input does not appear in the first form of the page *or*
- You are not setting the URL of your bookmark to that JS code and running it from there